# How to uninstall pyethapp?

Tags: installation, pyethapp

I want to uninstall pyethapp but I didn't found how to do this.

Someone can help me ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

pyethapp is a Python package.

[Python community package installation guide](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/installing/).

Use `pip` tool to install Python packages. If package is properly installed you can do:

```
pip uninstall pyethapp
```

If you did not install package using pip then just remove files from your hard disk.